# Static page caching using Nginx FastCGI Cache with CraftCMS

Tags: cache, nginx

This isn't Craft issue per se. But I was wondering if anyone can help me out. I’m trying to enable FastCGI Cache in my server. My nginx server block is coming from this helpful article: https://nystudio107.com/blog/static-caching-with-craft-cms.

The caching works because the site is now considerably faster. The issue is when I try to login in Craft's login page: `/admin/login`, it goes to `/admin` but it goes back to `/admin/login/` not to the dashboard page.

I have reached out to the article's author and he responded that,

> it isn't properly *not* stripping cookies off of the admin cp requests.

Here's my server block:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache/site levels=1:2 keys_zone=SITE:100m inactive=30m;

server {
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;
    root /var/www/site/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    ssi on;
    server_name site.ac;
    #404 error handler
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    #Cache everything by default
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    set $no_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST)
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* "/admin/|eecms/|actions/|cpresources/")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    # Craft-specific location handlers to ensure AdminCP requests route through index.php
    # If you change your `cpTrigger`, change it here as well
    location ^~ /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @phpfpm_nocache;
    }
    location ^~ /index.php/admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @phpfpm_nocache;
    }
    location ^~ /cpresources {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ^~ /eecms {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @phpfpm_nocache;
    }
    location ^~ /index.php/eecms {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @phpfpm_nocache;
    }
    #php-fpm configuration
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        # php-fpm parameters
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT "";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_HOST "127.0.0.1";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_NAME "x";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_USER "x";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_PASS "x";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_SITE_URL "http://site.ac/";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_BASE_URL "http://site.ac/";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH "/var/www/site/public/";
        # shared php-fpm configuration
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        # FastCGI Cache settings
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_cache SITE;
        fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    }
    # php-fpm configuration for non-cached content
    location @phpfpm_nocache {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $query_string;
        # php-fpm parameters
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT "";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_HOST "127.0.0.1";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_NAME "x";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_USER "x";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_DB_PASS "x";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_SITE_URL "http://site.ac/";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_BASE_URL "http://site.ac/";
        fastcgi_param CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH "/var/www/site/public/";
        # shared php-fpm configuration
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        # No FastCGI Cache
        fastcgi_cache_bypass 1;
        fastcgi_no_cache 1;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can shed some light on this issue I'm having. Any suggestions or comments is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Craft site? What is the `eecms` page?

Comment: Yes, it's a Craft site. I changed the cpTrigger to eecms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue had something to do with **PATH_INFO**. Adding '**usePathInfo => true**' in **general.php** fixed the issue. Here's the detailed explanation from Craft docs: https://craftcms.com/support/enable-path-info.

Comment: Ah glad you figured it out, thanks for sharing the answer.

Comment: @khalwat I should be the one thanking you. I love your articles. I learned a lot from them.

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to add something like this for your actions pages:

```
location ^~ /actions/users/setpassword {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @phpfpm_nocache;
}
```